# Displaying a subview when transitioning its container

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, subview, superview

When transitioning from one view controller to another, is it possible to animate a subview in the current container such that it stays on top for a brief moment and then it gets placed onto the new container after the transition is complete.

To understand what I mean, try e-mailing a photo from the photos app in iOS <5. The photo stays on top for a brief moment and then placed in the mail composer. In my case, I want the same effect when transitioning from one container to another.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on how you transition, but if you're using storyboards, this can probably be accomplished using a custom segue.